# Why is oatmeal considered chometz?

Tags: halacha, food, passover, chametz-leaven

Let's say a pot of raw dry oats becomes fully cooked in 5 minutes. Just oats and water. How is it considered chometz?

Comment: why would it not be chametz? (assuming oats are one of the 5 grain)

Comment: Are you heating this pot, or just soaking the oats in cold water?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12898/759 I'm not sure even that the 18 minute rule (if that's what you refer to) applies to all 5 grains in all their forms. It could be different consistencies and whatnot affect the time it takes to become chametz.

Comment: What about oatmeal cookies where you basically make matzo EXCEPT using whole oats in lumps rather than ground oats in sheets? Why is it chometz before cooking?

Comment: Can you describe these oatmeal cookies in more detail?

Comment: Also, why do you assume the oatmeal is Chametz?

Comment: For the record, that's only rolled oats that cook that quickly. Steel cut oats take 20-25 minutes to cook.

Answer (score 7):

The Shulchan Aruch (OC 555:3) rules that if one kneaded his dough with hot water it is forbidden, the assumption being that heat makes something become chametz quicker. This is also seen in the rule (559:1) not to knead the dough in the sun or in a room with a hot oven. Moreover one can leave dough in cold water indefinitely to prevent its becoming chametz (557:2).

Comment: Assuming the question means cooking with heat.

Comment: You can't kneed in hot water because by the time you're ready and cooked you're over the limit. I'm not asking about that. 5 minutes of hot water and oats in a pot is a lot less than 18 minutes of hot water and oats in an oven.

Comment: The whole point is that the 18 minutes (if that's what you're talking about; I don't see it in your question) is shortened when working in hot environments because things ferment quicker.

Comment: Of course, this is probably more accurately a case of Chalita which the Geonim forbade on Pesach (ShA OC 454:3)

Comment: Why does it make a difference whether the heat is during the kneading or after? (Besides, matzah factories are pretty hot, or at least the ones I've been to.)

Answer (score 3):

[Per OU.org](http://oukosher.org/passover/articles/which-foods-are-chametz-2/)

> Similarly, all oats are heat-treated to prevent them from becoming
>   rancid; if this heating is done with “wet” steam, the oats/oatmeal may
>   be chametz

Comment: He said they were raw and dry. You are talking about a different case.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/258/759